# should.match regex + variable chai expect in single line

Tags: regex, automated-tests, mocha.js, chai, e2e-testing

```
import 'mocha';
import * as chai from 'chai';
const should = chai.should();
const expect = chai.expect;

version = "2022-01-30"
let res = "/2022-01-30/images?$top=100&$filter=recordName eq 'R-00005593'"

#this works fine.
expect(res).to.match(/^\/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\/images\?\$top=100&\$filter=recordName eq 'R-\d{8}'$/);

#but I want to try with a variable version for the date.
expect(res).to.match(/^\/${version}\/images\?\$top=100&\$filter=recordName eq 'R-\d{8}'$/);
```

this is not working, any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use a variable inside a regular expression you should use the [RegExp constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp):

```js
expect(res).to.match(new RegExp(`^\\/${version}\\/images\\?\\$top=100&\\$filter=recordName eq 'R-\\d{8}'$`));
```

Comment: @SandyKool You are welcome. I would appreciate if you accept the answer if it answers your question.